# Change base DN of LDAP Directory to Organization

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I am trying to setup an ldap server for a small lab. The server is currently running Ubuntu 16.04.

The idea is to use the lab's name as the base DN of the directory.( Currently, 
its being set to the domain-name)

While, I did find some solutions that involved changing the slapd.conf file. Ubuntu doesn't have it.

Here is the layout of the /etc/ldap/ in the server.

```
├── ldap.conf
├── sasl2
├── schema
│   ├── collective.ldif
|   ... 
└── slapd.d
    ├── cn=config [error opening dir]
    └── cn=config.ldif
```

There isn't much in the `ldap.conf' file. Any ideas?